# How to load data to view with mediator pattern

Tags: javascript

Reading Addy Osmani's article "patterns for large-scale javascript application architecture". As I understand communication between modules proposed by broadcasting events through a mediator. Okay, but how do I load data from a model module to controller/view one and back? Or it supposed to preserve those in the same module? Hmm...

Comment: Hi, Have you tried javascript's MVC frameworks like AngularJs for example?

Comment: Backbone. There view connected to model directly, so it's not a mediator pattern implementation as I understand.